# Can I upgrade my 40amps breaker to 50amps or do I need rewiring?

Tags: circuit-breaker, glass-top-range

I have a 40amps range breaker. I want to upgrade it to 50amps. I know that the wires need to support 50amps if I want to upgrade it to 50amps. However, I am not able to figure out whether the wires support 50amps. How would I find out whether the wires support 50amps? Here is [image]the image of 40amps circuit breaker that I want to upgrade.

Comment: Do these wires go off into a *cable*, or a *conduit*?

Comment: Can you get a picture of any markings on the wires or the cable sheath the wires are coming out of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a number 6 wire. The picture looks like 8. It's written on the wire. Following AWG _

Comment: Wow your screen must be awesome I can't even see any writing+

Comment: Lol, just compare it to the 14 next to it.

Comment: Just wanted to know what the rating of the cook top is. Most cook tops are 40 amp max anyway. The max rating isn't a suggestion it's a requirement. It's to protect the unit in case of fault.